# Spring variable number of instances

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, runtime

I am getting into `Spring` now and I have a question. Let's assume we have an interface `IControl` and we have three implementations of it - e.g. `Button`, `Label`, `Checkbox`.
The user will enter a number `N` at runtime and I should create `N` controls of a specific type(`Button`, `Label` or `Checkbox`). The problem is I want this specific type to be configured before the program is run. For example I configure in my `spring.xml` that I want buttons, then the program is run, the user enters `10` and I create `10` buttons.

```
<beans>
   <bean id="controlCreator" class="org.company.ControlCreator">
       <property name="controlType" ref="?!?!?!?!?!?!"/>
   </bean>   
</beans>
```

How should I go configuring this?

P.S This is just a learning example I made up.

Best regards,
Petar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, allow me to state that Spring is not intended to do this.  Spring wants to an unintrusive method of wiring your components together.  It's not meant to be used for spawning objects at runtime.

### The correct approach

The correct approach would be to design a factory class.  You can set the defaults of this using Spring at startup, then ask the factory for instances at runtime.

### The intrusive apporach

If you really want to use Spring, you can do intrusively by asking the applicationContext for an instance of your control.

By default, all Spring beans are singletons, but you can make them into prototypes.

Disclaimer: code not tested, but should be something like this:

**Applicationcontext.xml**

```
<beans>
   <bean id="myButton" class="org.company.Control" scope="prototype">
       <property name="controlType" value="button" />
   </bean>   

   <bean id="controlCreator" class="org.company.ControlCreator" scope="singleton">
   </bean>   

</beans>
```

**Code**

```
public class controlCreator implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext appContext;

  public Control createButton(){
    // since this bean is prototype, a new one will be created like this
    return getApplicationContext().getBean("myButton");
  }


  // ... getter and setter for applicationContext

}
```

### The unintrusive approach

If you really want to use Spring, and you really want to use it unintrusively, you will have to use *Method Injection*.  Inject a factory method into your class.

The code would be the following:

**Applicationcontext.xml**

```
<beans>
   <bean id="myButton" class="org.company.Control" scope="prototype">
       <property name="controlType" value="button" />
   </bean>   

   <bean id="controlCreator" class="org.company.ControlCreator" scope="singleton">
       <lookup-method bean="myButton" name="createButton"/>
   </bean>   

</beans>
```

**Code**

```
public class controlCreator implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext appContext;

  public abstract Control createButton();


  // ... getter and setter for applicationContext

}
```

This will return the bean when the lookup method is called.  Since the bean is prototype, it will create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, that says it all. I guess I wanted to rely too much on Spring. Thanks again:)

Comment: Can we get a an example or a link to an example of **The Correct Approach**?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create N instances of same spring bean, as beans are singletons, and `ref` should reference this bean singleton.

What you can do is to make `controlCreator` abstract and then configure with different implementations which create different controls.

Comment: +1, I have something similar in mind now. `ControlCreator` will be a factory which receives an enumeration and returns a new control based on it. And in the client of `ControlCreator` I will inject the specific enum. Then the client will call `ControlCreator.getControl(enum)`. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Or you can pass enum to parameter `controlType`, but use `value` instead of `ref`: `<property name="controlType" value="button"/>`

Comment: You are right but please clear me why are you passing enumObject to getControl method if you already set it using dependency injection.

Comment: What I like about `Dependency Injection` is that it is changing your mindset. You start to think more in objects, I think:)

Comment: Not all spring beans are singletons. It depends on the scope you're using. By adding `scope="prototype"` to the bean definition you will get new spring beans at each request.

Comment: @Asad Rasheed - Either we set it in the factory with DI(and we don't pass enum in the method) or we set it in the client class with DI and then we pass it. Not in both places:)